# Ocultar botón en los últimos registros

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ajax que hace una consulta a la base de datos, los registros se envían de 20 en 20... Cada vez que hago clic en el botón cargar más me trae 20 regsitros, pero necesito que al pedir los últimos registros (20 o menos) se deje de muestrar el botón. Yo hice lo siguiente pero muestra primero los últimos registros y luego de presionar nuevamente el botón, este desaparece y quisiera que desaparezca con el último grupo de registros.

```
if (data.length <= 19){
    $('#btn-gallery').hide();
}
```

Comment: Dices 20 registros o menos, pero en el código pones 19 o menos. ¿No será que estás probando con un número de registros total que es un múltiplo de 20?

Comment: No me explique bien, la petición se hace de 20 en 20, pero la consulta puede traer 20, 21, 37, 40, 45,60... hasta 100. Incluso 19 o menos. Lo que deseo es que cuando sea la última tanda de registros, en ese momento se muestren y también se oculte el botón. Actualmente después que me entrega los útimos registros me muestrael botón y al hacer clic en el, desaparece.

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes en el javascript si has recibido la última tanda de registros?

Comment: Creo que te falta código relevante por añadir. Saludos

Comment: Cómo cuál? disculpa, pensé que era suficiente manejar el resultado que devuelve el ajax (Data), y decir, si son los últimos resultados... Hacer tal cosa.

Comment: No lo sé juanrpozo, por eso pido ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes basarte en el número de registros que te devuelve el servidor para saber si necesitas ocultar o no el botón "Cargar más".

Si el servidor te devuelve los registros de 20 en 20, y en una de las respuestas te da menos de 20, puedes inferir que no hay más registros.

Pero lo contrario no es cierto. Si en una página te devuelve 20 registros, no quiere decir que haya más registros. Sospecho que en tu base de datos de pruebas tienes un número de registros que es un múltiplo de 20, por ejemplo 100. El servidor te devuelve cinco páginas de 20 registros. Así que en la quinta página, como no has recibido menos de 20 registros, no ocultas el botón. Al pulsarlo otra vez, recibes 0 registros, y es entonces cuando ocultas el botón.

El servidor sí sabe cuántos registros hay en total, y te puede pasar esa información en la respuesta junto con los registros de la página solicitada. Por ejemplo:

```
request.data = {
  records => [
    { record1 },
    { record2 },
    ...
    { record20 }
  ],
  page => 4,
  pages => 5,
  records_per_page => 20,
  record_count => 100
};
```

La respuesta corresponde a la solicitud de la página 4 suponiendo que cada página tiene 20 registros. Y con esto puedes construir la interfaz sin ningún problema, lo mismo te sirve para saber si debes mostrar o no el botón de "Cargar más" (`request.data.page < request.data.pages`) que para hacer un control de navegación con botones "Atrás", "Adelante", etc.

Por supuesto, nada te impide responder sólo esto por ejemplo:

```
request.data = {
  records => [
    { record1 },
    { record2 },
    ...
    { record20 }
  ],
  has_more => true,
};
```

con `has_more=true` si hay más registros y `has_more=false` si es la última página.